# How to label my references so I know how to refer to them?

Tags: bibtex, best-practices, naming

I’m currently writing my master thesis and I have a lot of papers to cite. I’m not able to find a good way of giving shortcuts (names) for the papers when I cite them. Can you recommend a naming convention/style/standard for me please?

Comment: while working on the draft you can use `\usepackage{showkeys}` then the label will appear in the margin so you can see it when looking at the output, to save remembering it.

Comment: I use the first four letters of the authors name, followed by the two digit year.  If there are more than one cites in the same year/author, I add an "a", "b", etc.  So you might be `twai15` or I might be `segl06a`. Funny how I found in college everyone referred to textbooks by author and not title,  Decades later, I still remember those texts by their author, not their title.  In this spirit, I use the author truncation for cites.

Answer (score 2):

The keys I use are of the form

```
Last-XYZ:Keywords-From-Title
```

where

- `Last` is the last name of the first author
- `XYZ` are the initials of the last names of the remaining authors

For example

```
@Article{Abbena-G:cosymplectic,
  author =   {Abbena, E. and Grassi, A.},
  title =    {Hermitian left invariant metrics on complex Lie
                  groups and cosymplectic Hermitian manifolds},
  journaltitle = {Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. A (6)},
  fjournal =     {Unione Matematica Italiana. Bollettino. A. Serie VI},
  volume =   5,
  year =     1986,
  number =   3,
  pages =    {371--379},
}
```

I have one large `bib` file, currently running at nearly 40,000 lines and have been using this labelling system for over 20 years.  The following set of customizations in .emacs
gets `bibtex-mode` to make a good initial suggestion for me which I then edit by hand.

```
 '(bibtex-autokey-name-case-convert-function (quote capitalize))
 '(bibtex-autokey-name-separator "-")
 '(bibtex-autokey-name-year-separator "")
 '(bibtex-autokey-names (quote infty))
 '(bibtex-autokey-titleword-case-convert-function (quote identity))
 '(bibtex-autokey-titleword-length (quote infty))
 '(bibtex-autokey-titleword-separator "-")
 '(bibtex-autokey-titlewords 5)
 '(bibtex-autokey-year-length 0)
 '(bibtex-autokey-year-title-separator ":")
```

Using `reftex` mode in `emacs` I can quickly find references in my `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using JabRef. It has "Autogenerate BibTeX keys" button.

Mostly uses:
"Authors-Last-Name"Year

Answer (score 1):

I use `lastname.first_letter(s)_of_firstname:year:title`, where `title` is a single word representing the title. For example:

```
@article {nichols.a.e:1971:brief,
    author    = {Nichols, Ann Eljenholm},
    file      = {[[/home/me/library/Nichols, A. E.; 1971; Ælfric and the Brief Style.pdf]]}
    journal   = {Journal of English and Germanic Philology},
    month     = {Jan},
    number    = {1},
    pages     = {1–12},
    publisher = {University of Illinois Press},
    title     = {Ælfric and the Brief Style},
    url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/27705969},
    volume    = {70},
    year      = {1971},
}
```

If there is more than one author/editor, I add a `+` after the `first_letter_of_firstname`. For example:

```
@article {bamberg.m+:1990:boundaries,
    author       = {Bamberg, Michael and Marchman, Virginia},
    file         = {[[/home/me/library/Bamberg, M.+; 1990; What holds a narrative together.pdf]]}
    journaltitle = {Papers in Pragmatics},
    number       = {1},
    pages        = {58–121},
    subtitle     = {the linguistic encoding of episode boundaries},
    title        = {What holds a narrative together?},
    volume       = {4},
    year         = {1990},
}
```

If you are interested, you can take a look at [my Bib(La)TeX database](https://github.com/rwmpelstilzchen/bibliography.bib) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I think that having long BiBTeX keys harms the readability of the code, and this is not desired. I use short key like `Xy88` where `Xy` are the first two letters of the first author's family name and the two digits are for the year. If you have multiple papers sharing the same key you can add something like: `Xy88`, `Xy88a`, `Xy88b` etc.; for me it didn't happen often though.

**Note**: If you're collaborating, you should find a common understanding with you co-authors, otherwise it becomes a bigger issue.